# Laravel 10 extended model scope not working

Tags: laravel, eloquent, scope

I have pages with a "type" attribute and would like to filter an extended Model with an anonymous scope, so I can call them with `FieldPage::all()`. But it's not working. I get all pages (with mixed types).  What do I wrong?

This is my model

```php
class FieldPage extends Page {

    protected static function booted(): void
    {
        static::addGlobalScope('field_pages', function (Builder $builder) {
            $builder->where('type', '=', 'field');
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Try to remove 'field_pages' and keep function as first param

Comment: Nothing happens. Shows all mixed page types

Comment: Tried to replicate the bug but on my side scope does work. So problem should be somewhere else

Comment: which version of laravel are you using ?

Comment: laravel version is 10.6.1